# Inkscape: enlarge figure without creating distortions

Tags: inkscape, rescale

[(a) what I have, (b) what I get, (c) what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA2VT.png)

I have a simple vector graphic in Inkscape, which consists **of a rectangle, filled points and stars.** Since the axis ranges are not really nice (the height equals approximatly 3 times the width of the picture) for a publication, I want to rescale the picture. However, I do not have the raw data, such that I can plot it again. **How can I rescale my graphic (see figure (a)), such that the x-range is more wide (see figure (c)) without getting distortions (see figure (b))?** In the end I want to create a PDF file out of it.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it in 2 steps, using the *Object -> Transform tool* (<kbd>Shift-Ctrl-M</kbd>).

First, select everything, and with the transform tool select the *Scale* tab, and scale horizontally by, say, 300%. All figures will be distorted.

Now, unselect the rectangle, and scale horizontally again by 33.3%, but first click on *Apply to each object separately*. This will undo the distortion (but not the translation) of each object.

Note that 300% followed by 33.3% should leave the individual objects with the same size.

Documentation [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Transforms.html).